# Access class in dll?

Tags: c#

From the Main class of the Windows Form I'm trying to create an object of a class inside another library(dll).

But I can't create this object, because I don't get any help fom Visual Studio, when I'm typing the name of that class.

I guess I need a reference to the library and I have tried to right click on the library and then Add Reference and selected the name of the project where I have my Main class and Windows Form.

But It still isn't working! Have I done this wrong or have I missed something?

Comment: Have you used [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the following steps to `access` the method in `library` (dll), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

- Right click the `references` folder in your form project add click add reference select the project or folder of dll.
- Include the namespace of the dll in your class (Form) suppose you have namespace yourcomapany.communication then use `using` to include namespace to access classes in it.

  using yourcomapany.communication;

Comment: Then a message box pops up saying I can't add it and that it would cause circular dependency !?

Comment: Are you adding reference of project to itself? Add reference of library in the project where you want to use it

Comment: When I follow your steps, I get this message!?

Comment: This may help, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx, added in answer as well

Comment: At last I found the reason why i didn't work! In a previous attempt I add a reference the opposite way, but after I deleted that reference it worked fine! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

> But It still isn't working! Have I done wrong or I have I missed something?

Make sure that you have brought the namespace into which this class is defined into scope. So for example:

```
namespace FooBar
{
    public class Foo  
    {

    }
}
```

and then in your WinForms application after adding reference to the class library containing the class add the namespace:

```
using FooBar;
```

Now you could create instances:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Of course for this to work `Foo` must be declared as `public`. If it isn't then of course that you cannot access it. Remember that if there's no visibility modifier to the class:

```
namespace FooBar
{
    class Foo  
    {

    }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
namespace FooBar
{
    internal class Foo  
    {

    }
}
```

so `internal` is assumed which means that you cannot access it from another assembly. It must be `public`.

Comment: When I'm trying to write the namespace, I don't get any help to write. I take that as it has no "connection" !?

Comment: Did you reference the assembly containing this namespace to your project? If it is part of the same solution you could add directly a Project Reference.

Comment: Yes it's part of the same solution

Comment: The class is set to public by default, but still isn't working!?